# Spring Security 3 SHA-1 with Salt

Tags: java, xml, spring, security

I have a legacy application that we are rewriting and I am in the process of converting the existing user table.  The passwords were encrypted by using sha-1 with a salt.  Specifically salt+password.  Example, if the salt is ABC123 and the password is XYZ789 then the string that would be encrypted is ABC123XYZ789.  Spring Security by default encrypts the String XYZ789{ABC123}.  How do implement my own password encrypt/validation to bypass Spring Security's default encryption.

I can post my security xml but everything is working if I update the hashed password with the password{salt} encrypted.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: SHA-1 is a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) but not an [encryption function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subclass [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html) and override the `mergePasswordAndSalt(String, Object, boolean)` method. You can see [here, how it is originally implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.java#BasePasswordEncoder.mergePasswordAndSalt%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%29). Just modify the string concatenation part, and you are done.

Then, provide your own `passwordEncoder` like this:

```
<beans:bean 
    id="passwordEncoder" 
    class="my.awesome.package.MyAwesomeShaPasswordEncoder"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I implemented this and it worked perfectly.  Exactly what I was needing.